Macro to copy incrementing selections of values from one sheet to another
I am trying to write a vba loop in excel that copies a selection of cells that contain values from one sheet and then pastes those values into another sheet but am missing the vba skills to write what I am trying to do.
Each time the loop will need to increment the selection by 38 columns towards the right of the last 38 that was selected. In practice, the first selection to be copied would start at column A thru column AL, then the second selection to be copied would be column AM thru column BX, and so on.
The selection range will need to start at row 2 thru the last row of the second column being selected that contains a value. The selection will then be pasted to destination page starting at A2. Then the next selection will then need to start at the next blank row number in the column A of the sheet being pasted to.
I tried to write up a sudo script that hopefully conveys what I am trying to attempt to do, I'm sure a lot of the function's formatting is incorrect, yet I hope it is clear in what I am wanting to do.
SUDO SCRIPT EXAMPLE

i = 1
j = 38
k = 2
SET Length = LEN(ColumnID(j)) 'as numeric counted value. Stop counting rows in column once no value found
Sheet1.COPY SELECTION LEN(Row(2(ColumnID(i))) thru LEN(Row(2(ColumnID(j))) Sheet2.PASTE SELECTION Start PASTE at RowID(k) End PASTE at RowID(Length) 'COPY SELECTION should ignore first row entirely
i = 1 + j
j = j + 38
k = k + Length
Loop


Microsoft documentation:

Range.End property (Excel)


Range.Offset property (Excel)

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rngDes As Range
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long
    Dim LastRowS As Long, LastRowD As Long
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1") ' source sheet, modify as needed
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2") ' destination sheet
    Const COL_CNT = 38
    Const GROUP_CNT = 3 ' how many selection (38 Cols) to be copied
    For i = 1 To GROUP_CNT
        ' last data row# on source sheet
        LastRowS = oSht1.Cells(oSht1.Rows.Count, (i - 1) * COL_CNT + 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If LastRowS > 1 Then
            ' first blank cell on Col A on dest. sheet
            Set rngDes = oSht2.Cells(oSht2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            ' copy data to dest. sheet
            oSht1.Range("A2").Resize(LastRowS - 1, COL_CNT).Offset((i - 1) * COL_CNT).Copy rngDes
        End If
    Next
End Sub



Copy Adjacent Data Sets One Below the Other

Sub CopyDataSets()
    
    ' Constants
    
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A2"
    
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A2"
    Const DST_COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 3
    
    Const COPY_ONLY_VALUES As Boolean = False
    
    ' Workbook
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source Sheet
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range:
    With sws.UsedRange
        Set srg = sws.Range(sws.Range(SRC_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS), _
            .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge))
    End With
    
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    Dim SetsCount As Long: SetsCount = Int(scCount / DST_COLUMNS_COUNT)
    
    ' Destination Sheet
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim drrg As Range:
    Set drrg = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS).Resize(, DST_COLUMNS_COUNT)
    
    drrg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drrg.Row + 1).Clear
    
    ' Copy.
    
    Dim ssrg As Range, slcell As Range, s As Long, srCount As Long
    
    For s = 1 To SetsCount
        With srg.Resize(, DST_COLUMNS_COUNT) _
                .Offset(, (s - 1) * DST_COLUMNS_COUNT)
            Set slcell = .Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            If Not slcell Is Nothing Then
                srCount = slcell.Row - .Row + 1
                With .Resize(srCount)
                    If COPY_ONLY_VALUES Then
                        drrg.Resize(srCount).Value = .Value
                    Else
                        .Copy drrg
                    End If
                End With
                Set drrg = drrg.Offset(srCount)
            End If
        End With
    Next s
    
    'drrg.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Data sets copied.", vbInformation

End Sub

